# BCS and ADO.NET Entity Framework Store Procedure with VS2010

Tags: 2010

I have created ADO.NET entity framework with Sql Server and using this Model in .NET assembly connector now so far in Methods i have been View and Tables to get data from but now i would like to use store procedure to do CRUD Operation please advise me if anyone out there has done it or have any direction.

Thanks 
ROnak

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking why would you need to build your own Stored Procedure when the EF model should give you everything already. What I would see is however define required methods in your BDC Model besides Finder methods the CRUD and map them to actual code to perform Entity insertion.

See video here for EF Crud via Stored Procedures http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/wriju/CRUD-using-Stored-Procedure-in-ADONET-Entity-Framework-40 or example here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/crud-operations-with-stored-procedures-via-entity-data-model/

As a personal question: Unless you only have 1 entity, how would you expose all other EF entities?

Comment: Thanks Marius for answer i am not building store procedure i want to use SPs export into model but now i have clear picture as i need to function import in order to use SPs in EF.will give try and share result here.